# How to load existing VMWare Fusion from Mac OS X onto Windows PC?

Tags: windows-10, macos, virtualbox, vmware, vmware-fusion

I'm using a Mac **VMWare Fusions**, I have 6 appliances.

[image]

I want to reuse 1 of them, and load them into my Windows PC.

Which software should I use ?

- VirtualBox
- VMWare Work Station (recommended, since it is VMWare product ?)

How do I do it ?

- Do I need convert them first ?
- What options do I select to retore them ?

Comment: If it's for non-commercial use and if you don't need the features of VMware Workstation, you could run the VM in VMware Player, which is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VMware Workstation and you do not need to convert the file. Copy the VMware Fusion machine folder (all the files) to the Windows machine with VMware Workstation and it should open.

Please see the VMware Knowledgebase article below and note carefully the version requirements

> Yes you can go both ways, it's not a problem at all. As long as you
>   stick with the same time era product versions (eg. Fusion 8.x and
>   Workstation12.x) then the trouble is minimal.

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/551630

Comment: Thank John, will note your comments.

Comment: You are most welcome